# symfony doctrine arrayCollection return 1 item

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Hi i have problem with get participants i get only 1 participants but must be more.

Group Entity:

```
/**
 * One Group has Many participants.
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserActivity", mappedBy="group")
 */
private $participants;


public function __construct() {
    $this->participants = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

UserActivity entity:

```
    /**
     * @var User $user
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="UserActivity")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;


    /**
     * @var Group $group
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="InformalGroup", inversedBy="UserActivity")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $group;


/**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="accepted", type="datetime")
     */
    private $accepted;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deleted;
```

User entity:

```
      /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $userActivity
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserActivity", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $userActivity;

  public function __construct() {
        $this->userActivity = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

I don't know how to do that i will can get group by id, and in this group get participants all who have relation in UserActivity.

Comment: i can't use many to many because my userActivity  entity ( users_groups ) have more than user_id and group_id , accepted date and deleted.

Comment: I need entity but not join table for relation

Comment: @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="InformalGroup", inversedBy="UserActivity"). InformalGroup must be the name of a entity and UserActivity is the property inside that entity. Looks like this is incorrect. UserActivity should also start with a lowercase letter http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: maybe `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate` can give you some useful info

Comment: [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'AppBundle\Entity\InformalGroup' mapping is invalid:
* The mappings AppBundle\Entity\InformalGroup#participants and AppBundle\Entity\UserActivity#group are inconsistent with each other.

Comment: [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'AppBundle\Entity\UserActivity' mapping is invalid:
* The association AppBundle\Entity\UserActivity#user refers to the inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\User#UserActivity which does not exist.
* The association AppBundle\Entity\UserActivity#group refers to the inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\InformalGroup#UserActivity which does not exist.

Comment: maybe somebody can show example how related participants variable?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from annotations, the `mappedBy` and `inversedBy` properties were wrong, they must target an entity attribute (thus need to give the same name).

Group entity:

```
// AppBundle\Entity\InformalGroup.php

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserActivity", mappedBy="group")
 */
private $participants;
```

UserActivity entity:

```
// AppBundle\Entity\UserActivity.php

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\InformalGroup", inversedBy="participants")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $group;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="userActivity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $user;
```

User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserActivity", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $userActivity;
```

You can have a deeper look about doctrine annotations in the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annotations-reference).